# MacbookPro 2018 13inch switches off frequently due to panic issue

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, catalina, memory

My macbook pro 2018 is 13 inch model with 8GB RAM and 2.3 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5 processor. When I am working on couple of application mainly chrome browser laptop will suddenly switched off. Later I stopped using chrome, this morning I was on call in Teams with couple of other apps open. The laptop suddenly switched off and I switched it ON using power button. All the previously opened apps will start booting up after signing in to dashboard. Once all apps are opened within few seconds macbook is getting switched off.
This happened two times. On third time I closed all the application to start working.
On every restart, I am getting following below error:

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual text (not an image) of the error as it's contents aren't searchable.  We also have to go off site (away from the question) to actually read it.  Post the error to the original question with an [edit], not to the comments.  Also, there's info missing from the panic report (scroll down).  Please include that as well.

Comment: Yes, I thought so to do while posting the question. I forgot to  copy the error to text note and I have the screenshot alone now. I will update the ticket after I face the issuee again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is technically called a 'kernel panic'.

If you want to try a few easy things, follow the instructions on this apple support page regarding this error:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200553
Basically install any OS updates available, install software updates for other apps and drivers, reboot in safe mode, reset NVRAM, disconnect all the external devices.

Also you could try a hardware diagnostic by rebooting while you hold down the COMMAND key and the D key at the same time.

However, if you're near an Apple store, **I highly recommend making a genius bar appointment to have them take a look at it**. They will do a brief look for free, and give you a recommendation for what to do next.  Here is the link to do that:
https://getsupport.apple.com/

1. Click Mac
2. Click Mac Notebooks
3. TYPE IN "restart" into the text bar
4. click "Unexpected shutdown or restart" Click Bring In For Repair
5. Sign in with your Apple ID
6. Follow the instructions.

Comment: Thank you Steamfire. I will try the suggestion.